# Possible Threats from prolonged white noise exposure

Tags: hearing, ear, white-noise

A white noise (eg. Normal Rain) has loudness around 65dB. Although for an adult, on a standard basis,  there are max 8 hours recommended exposure for 85dB [See chart](https://www.noisehelp.com/noise-dose.html). Still, can a prolonged stretch (10-15 hours) of white noise exposure harm human ear?

Comment: I think that's going to depend strictly on volume. The fact that it's white noise isn't going to matter.

Comment: @CareyGregory White noise, or even better pink noise, spreads the energy across the entire cochlea, whereas a tone focuses all the energy on a specific location. The spectrum definitely matters.

Comment: @StrongBad Then you should write an answer and explain.